# Rails activerecord : sum, max and joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models `users` and `posts`. An user can votes and views a post

```
#users
  id
  name

#posts
  id
  count_votes
  count_views
  users_id
  created_at
  updated_at
```

I want the user who received the most votes and views on his posts from the last 24 hours. The biggest sum of views and votes win.

**WHAT I TRIED**
I have this SQL query, it's good but I would like to have the user with the max of votes, this one give me all users and I don't know how to add count_views

```
select u.name as "Name", sum(p.count_votes)
from posts p 
inner join users u on p.user_id = u.id 
where p.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)
group by user_id;
```

ActiveRecord version

```
Post.select("users.id, sum(posts.count_votes) as nb_votes")
.joins(:user).where("posts.created_at >= ?", 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day)
.group("posts.user_id")

# Results on IRB
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1>, #<Post id: 3>]>
```

How can I combine a sum and a max on these two sums ? Is there a way to have an activerecord code or only raw SQL ?

Comment: does my answer below helped you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You current query does a grouping on user. So you would get one record for each user in the output. By limiting the output to just 1 record and ordering by votes+views total count, you can get the top user.

Raw SQL:

```
select u.id, sum(p.count_votes + p.count_views) total
from posts p 
inner join users u on p.user_id = u.id 
where p.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)
group by u.id
order by total DESC
limit 1 ;
```

ActiveRecord version: Start from your User model, so you will get the user object in the output instead of Post object, like you have mentioned in the question.

```
User.select("users.id, sum(posts.count_votes + posts.count_views) as nb_votes")
.joins(:post).where("posts.created_at >= ?", 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day)
.group("posts.user_id").order("nb_votes DESC").limit(1)
```

Comment: You may need `order by total DESC` to get max result

Comment: @emaillenin rails newbie here! `on p.user_id = u.id ` part is missing in ActiveRecord version. How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord makes sense once you work with an object, in that case you need to have a User object only, so here is your solution below:

```
  sql = %Q(SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE id = (SELECT users_id FROM posts
    WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
    ORDER BY count_votes DESC, count_views DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) 
  LIMIT 1)

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: The answer from @emaillenin is more complete. He gaves me the rails code I was searching for. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Ludovic I've updated the answer to wrap the SQL call with ActiveRecord helper. Try to perform query execution plan to compare the two calls, here is an significant difference.