# ActiveRecord Sum Max Joins results in array with multiple nil ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, sum

Same Question as [Rails activerecord : sum, max and joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440754/rails-activerecord-sum-max-and-joins)

except getting strange results.

```
class CustomResumeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resumeline_words
end

class ResumelineWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_resumeline
end

CustomResumeline.joins(:resumeline_words).where(resumeline_words: {name: ["time", "data"]}).select('sum(resumeline_words.weight) as nb_votes').group('resumeline_words.custom_resumeline_id').order('nb_votes ASC')
```

Results

```
CustomResumeline Load (0.8ms)  SELECT sum(resumeline_words.weight) as nb_votes FROM "custom_resumelines" INNER JOIN "resumeline_words" ON "resumeline_words"."custom_resumeline_id" = "custom_resumelines"."id" WHERE "resumeline_words"."name" IN ('time', 'data') GROUP BY resumeline_words.custom_resumeline_id  ORDER BY nb_votes ASC
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, #<CustomResumeline id: nil>, ...]>
```

My question is, why am I getting an array with a bunch of nil id CustomResumelines ?

Thanks

Comment: Change the `joins` for a `includes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your query, you are using `#select` to

```
result =  CustomResumeline.joins(:resumeline_words)...
```

`result` returns a *relation* object, where `id` will added by Rails as you used `#select`, although you have not selected it. You can do now

```
result. map { |rec| rec.nb_votes }
# will give array of `nb_votes` values.
```

Some hints from [Selecting Specific Fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) guide :

> `Client.select("viewable_by, locked")` - to select only viewable_by and locked columns. Be careful because this also means you're **initializing** a *model object* with only the fields that you've selected. If you attempt to access a field that is not in the initialized record you'll receive: `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: <attribute>`. Where `<attribute>` is the attribute you asked for. The `id` method will not raise the `ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError`, so just be careful when working with *associations* because they need the id method to function properly.

So **The `id` method will not raise the `ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError`,..** -- Why ? As `#select` add it by default it to each model object created by it with a value of `id` as `nil`.

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks! This worked for me. I was wondering though, if I used a different grouping element like something called resumeline_id, could I get a result to look like [resumeline_id = > custom_resumeline_id],... with the order still determined by nb_votes

Comment: Sorry, I got it in the end. Thanks again. Mapping creates an array. I was looking for something that naturally builds a hash.