# ActiveRecord - Getting the sum of user score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an "ITEMS" database made of; ITEM_ID, OWNER_ID and VALUE.

An owner can own unlimited items. An item can only have one owner.

And I have an "OWNER" database made of; ID, NAME

I want to find the NAMES of top 10 RICHEST (wealthier) people. How can I do that?

First, I need to sum the values of an owner_id; than compare that with others?

Comment: my db name is "items"

Comment: Are you using MySql/Postgresql ?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: And I have another table owner with names. I need to get the names of top ten richest.

Comment: My query didn't work ?

Comment: I've updated the question, there is one more step needed. But your query seems fine up to now. don't have enouh reputation to upvote yet :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is kinda long solution but it worked for me:

```
    toplist = []
    all_owners = Owner.all
    all_owners.each do |owner|
        name = Owner.find(owner).name
        owner_value = Item.where(owner_id: owner).sum(:value)
        toplist << [owner_value,name]
    end
    @top10 = toplist.sort.last(10).reverse
```

Comment: To whom decided answer is NOT useful: This is the exact answer for my question and you downvote it? So, please tell us your perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do :

```
Item.group(:owner_id) # grouping Items by owner id
    .select("SUM(value) as sum") # summing values of each group
    .order("sum DESC") # ordering resulting records by the sum value
    .limit(10) # giving the top 10 records
```

Comment: I only get nill with this query.

Comment: No.. You have to iterate through.. to get the original stuffs.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683033/activerecord-sum-max-joins-results-in-array-with-multiple-nil-ids/28683157?noredirect=1#comment45754852_28683157